# Ad hoc distribution to an external client?

Tags: ios, ipad, distribution, adhoc

I have built an iOS app that is a custom business app for a small number of our external clients. It would be an add-on to other applications/services we are providing them. What is the best way to distribute this app?

Can we use ad-hoc distribution to distribute iOS apps to external clients? The 100 device limit is not a big issue in this case. This is a question of legality, not of whether it is technically possible.

The apple documentation that I have read has not been real clear on this point.

--Thanks for you help!
Mike C.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the US you could investigate the Apple-hosted Custom B2B apps option for distribution through the App Store to businesses in the Volume Purchasing Programme (free to register for your customers).

The App Store Volume Purchase Program is also expanding to new countries soon according to it's [web page](http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/) (Australia, Canada, France, Germany, Italy, Japan, New Zealand, Spain and the  UK).

You might also want to view the WWDC 2012 video "Session 311 - Building and Distributing Custom B2B Apps for iOS"

Comment: Thanks, I watched the video and it was informative. We may need to do B2B. However, I know my boss would still rather do the ad-hoc distribution if possible - less overhead.

Comment: I understand and provided you are always and forever under the 100 device limit it should be OK.  But do bear in mind that at some point your business / clients or number of devices will expand or you will want to sell overseas.  It will be cheaper in the long run if you start planning the transition now especially as you may need to educate your customers.

Comment: After doing some more research it has become clear that Apple wants us to do what you suggested with the B2B. The ad-hoc provisioning expiration (1 year?) makes that pretty evident. I am going to try and convince my Boss to go that direction.

Comment: Yes - the WWDC videos (plus expanded country support) makes that clear.  My guess is that the next step will be from the VPP to upgrade pricing (but who knows when).